# Extra Space Before and After HTML Table

Tags: html, html-table, whitespace

I am trying to create a resume website with HTML CSS and Javascript.  I have tables in my website that I can't seem to move closer together vertically.  I've tried using CSS like `margin: 0;` and `padding: 0;` in both `table`, `tr`, and `td` but not luck.  Can anybody help me out?

I can't post an image because I have to have at least 10 reputation.  But basically there are two tables on top of one another and in between them there is space that I would like to get rid of.

Comment: Post your code and maybe a fiddle.

Comment: Fiddle it: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You could also go into youre F12 Developer Tools in the browser and select one table to see what creates the space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often separating tags using a new line will result in the browser rendering a small margin.

Example:

```
<div>
...
</div>
<div>
...
</div>
```

Is not the same as:

```
<div>
...
</div><div>
...
</div>
```

See if this is the case with your closing `</table>` tag and the tag that follows it.

Also check if your table has a border.

Comment: Hey thanks for helping, I've moved my table tr td and div tags around to remove spacing, but it didn't work

Comment: You need to Show us your HTML Markup

Comment: Go to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), paste your markup (HTML code) in the first box and click 'Save' at the top. Then post the link here.